# How do I set up a triple integral with vague parameters in the z coordinate direction?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The problem asks to find the volume of the solid bounded by $z = 16xy,~ z \geq 0,~ 0 \leq x \leq 5,~ 0 \leq y \leq 4$. But I am having trouble setting up the integral for the $z$ parameters.

Any help setting up the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: instead of vague, write variable or varying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $z = 16xy \ge 0$ for all $0 \le x \le 5$ and $0 \le y \le 4$. So, the bounds for $z$ are $0 \le z \le 16xy$.

Then, you get the integral $V = \int_0^5\int_0^4 \int_0^{16xy} \,dz\,dy\,dx$.

Alternatively, you can just use a double integral $V = \int_0^5\int_0^4 16xy\,dy\,dx$.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out maybe seconds after I posted! But thank you!!